# No space issue Jenkins - in docker

Tags: jenkins, docker

I am running Jenkins inside docker.
i receive the following space issue.

```
gzip: /tmp/sbt_a74fec8a/xoquick-1.0.tar.gz: No space left on device
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error gziping /tmp/sbt_a74fec8a/xoquick-1.0.tar. Exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives$.gzip(Archives.scala:93)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives$$anonfun$9.apply(Archives.scala:111)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives$$anonfun$9.apply(Archives.scala:111)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives$$anonfun$makeTarball$1.apply(Archives.scala:136)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives$$anonfun$makeTarball$1.apply(Archives.scala:118)
    at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:285)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives$.makeTarball(Archives.scala:118)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives$$anonfun$10.apply(Archives.scala:111)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives$$anonfun$10.apply(Archives.scala:111)
    at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:35)
    at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (universal:packageZipTarball) Error gziping /tmp/sbt_a74fec8a/xoquick-1.0.tar. Exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Feb 5, 2015 9:41:58 AM
Build step 'Build using sbt' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Build using sbt' marked build as failure
SSH: Current build result is [FAILURE], not going to run.
Finished: FAILURE
```

In docker I navigated to `/tmp` folder

```
cd /tmp/
```

and then

```
df -h .

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/mapper/docker-253:2-18350588-5a4c880a0e55c5b8a78ca16e7ef7fbedb7559cf07b3e249f81b88809901cca72
                  9.9G  9.1G  316M  97% /
```

I have sufficient place left inside.Why is the job failing to work?

i have checked this http://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/02/no-space-left-on-device-running-out-of-inodes.html

No issue with inode also.There is sufficient inodes available.Can somebody tell me what is the problem?

Comment: 316M of free disk space is not big amount, especially when you run jenkins job. It might create tmp files which will consume rest of the free space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins jobs can typically consume more that ~300m of space with all build artefacts, whatever you upload to your Docker container, the size of your version control checkout etc.

Add this to root's crontab to clean old containers periodically. Enter `sudo crontab -e` to edit:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
@daily  (echo "Cleaning Docker images at $(date):"; docker rm $(docker ps -a -q); docker rmi $(docker images | grep '<none>' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3)) &>> /var/log/dockerClean.log
```

(you could substitute adding the `SHELL` line for `2>&1 > /var/log/dockerClean.log` if you prefer `sh`, or omit it and make no change if `bash` is default on your system)

Comment: Hi Andy,The jenkins itself is running inside a docker container.There is a lot of space left in the main system

Comment: Another question is why is 9.9GB not getting expanded?Is there any memory limitation?

Comment: a container is limited to 10 GB by default, see http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/01/29/docker-device-mapper-resize/

Comment: Fixed the issue by following:
1)Mounted the JENKINS_HOME i.e outside docker i.e using -v command

    docker run -v <mylocation>:/var/lib/jenkins <jenkinscontainer> /bin/bash

Reason: Container space limitation to 10 GB.